# How to do Server side validation using Uploadify plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, upload, uploadify

I would like to do below validations for single file uploaded using jQuery [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com) plugin.

> 1. Check for the file type .jpg, .png & .gif
> 2. Check for the file size maximum 2MB only

I have done this through `fileExt` & `sizeLimit` options, but as the plugin developer says, one can easily bypass the `fileExt` validation & server side validation is recommended.

I want to do this using PHP server side scripting language.

I have already checked the documentation of the plugin & nothing helpful found there. 
Can someone please suggest how to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the [filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) and [exif_imagetype](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) functions to assess the file. The following should point you in the right direction:

```
$up_file = "file_the_user_uploaded";
$two_mb = 2097152;
if (filesize($up_file) < $two_mb) {
    if (exif_imagetype($up_file) > 0 && exif_imagetype($up_file) < 4) {
        // the file is .gif, .jpg, or .png and less than 2MB
        // do something to approve the file upload
    }
}
```

Note that the `filesize()` function in PHP returns the size in bytes, thus, the file should be less than `$two_mb` bytes. Also, the `exif_imagetype()` returns an integer code mapping to the MIME type of the uploaded image: 1, 2, 3, being `.gif`, `.jpg`, and `.png` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the validation on the script that processes the file upload. It is not a pre-validation.

You can use [exif_imagetype](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) to make sure it is an image file.

Use `filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) < 2000000` to validate the size of the file.